# how to know the version of homestead installed

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I can't remember what version was installed and I want to see know but I don't know how. Probably there will be some command to the terminal but I can't figure out.

Can anyone tell me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe a `git status` in the Homestead directory should do it.

Comment: it works, thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

For newcomers to *Laravel*, this depends on what instance of *Homestead* you're working with (how you've chosen to install *Homestead*).

### Per-project installation

```
# From your project directory, run this
php vendor/bin/homestead --version
```

### Global installation

```
# If you've already set homestead in PATH env
homestead --version

# If you haven't
php ~/Homestead/homestead --version
```

Hope this saves you some minutes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the version of Homestead repository you can check using following command on ~/Homestead

```
$ git branch -v
```

and the result would be something like this

```
* master 09fce4c Tag v10.0.2
```

and here it is v10.0.2

Answer (score 0):

you can use -v or --version

```
homestead --version
```

> **Versions:**
>
> - Vagrant: Run vagrant -v to show the version.
> - Provider: Virtualbox, VMWare or Parallels and it's version.
> - Homestead: Run homestead --version to show the version.

Comment: try that in laravel directory if you sure installed homestead and export path